# Abort an Alamofire download request before it completes

Tags: swift, alamofire

I instantiate a request to download a remote mp3 file via Alamofire. This file automatically plays when the download is complete. I'm trying to cancel the request if the user decides to leave the screen before completion. This works only if the download is complete, while it gives me a -999 error code if I cancel during the downloading process.

I've tried everything regarding canceling an Alamofire request, but nothing seems to work.

```
func startDownload(audioUrl: String) -> Void {

    audioFileURL = self.getSaveFileUrl(fileName: audioUrl)

    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        return (self.audioFileURL!, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    self.request = Alamofire.download(audioUrl, to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: {(progress) in
        // Download in progress
        let roundedNum = progress.fractionCompleted*100
        let roundedString = String(format: "%.0f", roundedNum)
        self.topLabel.text = "\(roundedString)%"

        }).response(completionHandler: {(DefaultDownloadResponse) in
            // Download completed
            self.topLabel.text = "Now playing"
            self.playAudio()
        })
}
```

Then when the user exits the screen I trigger the following:

```
@IBAction func dismissPlayVC(_ sender: Any) {
    self.request?.cancel() // Cancelling the download request when exiting PlayVC
    player.pause() // Pause player if audio is playing while exiting PlayVC
    if let urlString = audioUrlString {
        clearDiskCache(audioUrl: urlString)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The request is instantiated at the beginning like so:

```
    var request: Alamofire.Request?
```

Any suggestions? The error code is -999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error `-999` is the cancellation error returned by the system. It just means the ongoing `URLSessionTask` was cancelled before completing. We've made it an explicit error in Alamofire 5, but it's still considered an error state, so if you need separate handling, you can do so in your `response` closure.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining it. Thought the task is not being canceled, the mp3 starts playing anyway, even after the self.request?.cancel() call. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Like I said, in your `response` closure, check if the response failed and don't play the file if it did.

Comment: Thanks that does work. I am leaving the self.request?.cancel() in the dismiss action and checking inside the closure.